# Unknown Database Error python mysql

Tags: python, mysql, database

This link contains shows the database I've created in the mysql workbench and the connection I have established in the code but the database is unknown for some reason. Is there a step I've missed?
http://gyazo.com/d995c4da99043da43bfbd057a0a839c7

```
__author__ = 'avi'

from TwitterSearch import *
import json

twtsearch = TwitterSearch(
    consumer_key='PXTUrlRfgC1zSTsAPU9z6EHtD',
    consumer_secret='qM9F4FVj1qLFc6f795r96DQPNAJO8hkbWy4PXWYLfQcYyNGY7D',
    access_token='2943116292-wVHEjbfjX7OFqaOURBqim5o7Vs6lZyjxsoto8nD',
    access_token_secret='CJAppSRY9TZ5cwYTABZhH2YTd0rm5IzBDqPder6v4qLBA'
    )

twtsearchorder = TwitterSearchOrder()
twtsearchorder.set_keywords(['iphone6'])
twtsearchorder.set_language('en')
twtsearchorder.set_include_entities(True)


tweet_limit=50
parsed_tweets= {}
table="twtinfo"
import MySQLdb as mdb

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root','root','tweetinfo')
cur=con.cursor()

for tweet in twtsearch.search_tweets_iterable(twtsearchorder):
    if tweet_limit > 0 :
        parsed_tweets['name'] = tweet['user']['screen_name']
        parsed_tweets['content'] = tweet['text']
        parsed_tweets['user_id'] = tweet['user']['id']
        parsed_tweets['fav_count'] = tweet['favorite_count']
        parsed_tweets['location'] = tweet['user']['location']
        parsed_tweets['retweet_count'] = tweet['retweet_count']
        placeholders= ', '.join(['%s'] *len(parsed_tweets))
        columns = ', '.join(parsed_tweets.keys())
        sql="INSERT into %s ( %s ) VALUES ( %s )" % (table, columns, placeholders)
        cur.execute(sql,parsed_tweets.values())
        tweet_limit -= 1
```

Comment: Link seems to show a broken file at gyazo.

Comment: seems to work fine for me  http://gyazo.com/d995c4da99043da43bfbd057a0a839c7

Comment: To debug something like this, start with just the database connection.  Make sure that you can properly connect to the database and close the connection.  From a quick glance, it looks like your connection string may not be properly specified.  Once you know you can connect, try something simple, like a SELECT on a single column.

Comment: establishing the connection is the problem here, I just tried a simple select statement like you've mentioned and it doesn't execute because it doesn't recognise that the database even exists. Is there anything incorrect in my syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL process is complaining about the database you are trying to access, namely `tweetinfo` isn't existing. MySQL error 1049 is usually an indication of having to forgot to select a database, but you did as forth argument to `mdb.connect()`

Possible errors could be:

- That you have several MySQL processes running, with the one with the proper database not being on the default MySQL port.
- That somehow your database GUI application hasn't actually submitted your database and table to the MySQL process.
- That MySQL isn't running? You would probably get a different error message for that, but it could be an idea to make sure it is just in case.

Just to check if your tables exists and that your database is in place, open a terminal and write the following commands:

```
mysql -u root -proot
use tweetinfo;
show create table twtinfo;
```

Another thing to try could be to ask the MySQL process about which database it thinks you are using. Try adding something like the following to your code:

```
cur.execute("SELECT DATABASE() FROM DUAL;")
print("Database is: %s.", cur.fetchone()[0])
```

I'm not a python programmer, so I'm not entirely confident that will work without some adjustments.

If none of this gave you a good lead, I'm not quite sure what's wrong.

Comment: It says mysql isn't a recognized command on the terminal.Do I have to type it from a particular directory?

Comment: It seems mysql.exe is not in a folder listed in your PATH environment variable. Restarting your GUI and making sure everything is still there would be another way, or looking for some kind of commit or save button that looks special.

Comment: Your GUI application probably has a window where you can write commands by hand and execute them. That would be a good place to type `use tweetinfo;` and `show create table twtinfo;`. It will probably be named `MySQL query window` or something similar.

Comment: In your MySQL Workbench open, visible on your screenshot, there are two tabs named "Local instance MySQL56". Are you sure you don't have two MySQL processes running, and that you python code connects to the wrong one?

Comment: The problem was that I hadn't created the schema on the instance of the mysql server that was running. I had it setup as a model where it presumably existed without a connection. Now I have other troubles but atleast I know the connection holds now. Thanks! http://gyazo.com/816e7c8f253593f763561798c2d65075